# Multiple Devexpress aspxgridlookup control in a web page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, css, devexpress

I have 4 aspxgridlookup controls in a page. Each of them makes a new line at the end of them, because their are in tables by default. Then I could not put all of them in a single line in the page(displaying elements inline).
Is there any solution for putting aspxgridlookup controls in a single line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used css to solve my problem.

```css
display: inline-block; 
vertical-align: top; 
margin-left:2px;
```